# Custom cypress commands is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Chainable<any>

Tags: javascript, typescript, automation, cypress

In a .ts file I create a test to try and access a custom created command from command.js, `createInbox` function is underlined with red with the following message : Property 'createInbox' does not exist on type 'cy & EventEmitter

```
it.only('dsdsds', () => {
    cy.createInbox().then((inbox) => { 
      console.log(inbox);
      // { id: '...', emailAddress: '...' }
    });
  })
```

My command.js file look like this

```
const { MailSlurp } = require("mailslurp-client");
const mailslurp = new MailSlurp(Cypress.env("mailSlurpApiKey"));

Cypress.Commands.add("createInbox", () => {
  return mailslurp.createInbox();
});

Cypress.Commands.add("waitForLatestEmail", (inboxId) => {
  return mailslurp.waitForLatestEmail(inboxId);
});
```

I understand that I have to rename command.js to ts, however when I do that all custom commands is underlined with red with the following error :
Argument of type '"waitForLatestEmail"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof Chainable

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by adding custom chainable interface to support folder

```
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable {
    createInbox(): Chainable<any>;
    waitForLatestEmail(inboxId: number): Chainable<any>;
  }
}
```

Comment: it's better to parameterize the Chainable type with the actual return type: `createInbox(): Chainable<InboxDto>;`

Comment: @MikhailBolotov but isnt that means you need to create another class where all that data will be mapped to, its a bit complicated no when i just need two values from it, however you probably right

Comment: Usually, you have that class already declared in type definitions of the library. For the mail client, it seems they can be found inside `node_modules\mailslurp-client` directory

Comment: @MikhailBolotov if i do it then i get the follow error Type 'Chainable' is not generic

export class InboxDto {

  emailAddress: string;
  id: string;

}

Comment: you could try to define the `interface Chainable` as `interface Chainable<Subject = any>`

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem aswell!
My solution:
I had my *.d.ts files located inside the cypress/support folder, right next to the *.ts files with all the custom commands. Moving those outside(!) the "support"-folder and into another one called "definitionFiles" (for example) worked beautifully!

Comment: Can you provide code?